# Defining an Array in the fixtures and utilizing it in the main test case. Cypress Fixture throws a Type Error?

Tags: arrays, cypress, fixtures

I am trying a test case with the help of the fixtures in Cypress. I have got the `userdata.json` folder under the `../cypress/fixtures` folder.
When I try to run the test I always get this error `TypeError` `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'assets')`
Please find the code and other details here:

The `.json` file looks like this:

```
{
 "email" : "****",
 "password" : "****",
 "title" : "dashboard",
 "number" : "12",
 "assets" : ["birthday-cake.jpg","cupcake.jpg","cake-black.jpg","building-1.jpg","building-2.jpg","cake-1.jpg","cake-2.jpg","cake-3.jpg","cake-4.jpg","car-1.jpg","car-2.jpg","car-3.png","longvideo.mp4","shortvideo.mp4","skyscrapper.jpg"]
}
```

My code looks like this :

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe('Getting the names of the assets and iterating to find repeated names', ()=> {
    
    before(function() {
        cy.fixture('userdata').then(function(value){
            this.value=value
        })
    })
    it('login',function() {
        cy.visit('https://sample-staging.com/login')
        cy.url().should('include','staging')
        cy.get('input[type="email"]').type(this.value.email).should('have.value',this.value.email)
        cy.get('input[type="password"]').type(this.value.password).should('have.value',this.value.password)
        cy.get('button').contains('Login').click()
        cy.wait(5000)
        cy.url().should('include',this.value.title) 
    })
    it('Creating a new playlist', function() {
        cy.get('.text-xfm').contains('PLAYLISTS').click()
        cy.wait(5000)
        cy.get('div.text-xfs').contains('Add New').click()
        cy.get('label.text-xfx').should('contain','Playlist name is required')
        cy.get('#playlistName').type('Test-Playlist').should('have.value','Test-Playlist')
        cy.get('span.text-xfs').should('have.text','Choose assets to add to playlist').click()
        cy.wait(5000)
        cy.get('div.overflow-scroll').should('be.visible')
        cy.log(this.value.assets)
        this.value.assets.forEach(function(element)  {
            cy.selectAsset(element)
        });

        
            
    })
})
```

I have also created a custom command - `selectAsset` which is in the `commands.json`

I am not sure what I missed I tried all the answers that I have seen so far but always I get this error.
Find the screenshot here -
[Test case passing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTclX.png)
[Throwing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wx88.png)

As it can be seen all the places where I use the fixture like email, password, title are all passing except the array - `assets`.
Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `before` you have to use `beforeEach` because cypress clears aliases between tests. So your first `it` block is able to access the fixture values where as the second one isn't.

From [Cypress Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Aliases)

> Under the hood, aliasing basic objects and primitives utilizes Mocha's
> shared context object: that is, aliases are available as this.*.
>
> Mocha automatically shares contexts for us across all applicable hooks
> for each test. Additionally these aliases and properties are
> automatically cleaned up after each test.

```js
describe('Getting the names of the assets and iterating to find repeated names', () => {
  beforeEach(function () {
    cy.fixture('userdata').then(function (value) {
      this.value = value
    })
  })

  it('login', function () {
    cy.visit('https://manager-staging.xogo.io/login')
    cy.url().should('include', 'staging')
    cy.get('input[type="email"]')
      .type(this.value.email)
      .should('have.value', this.value.email)
    cy.get('input[type="password"]')
      .type(this.value.password)
      .should('have.value', this.value.password)
    cy.get('button').contains('Login').click()
    cy.wait(5000)
    cy.url().should('include', this.value.title)
  })

  it('Creating a new playlist', function () {
    cy.get('.text-xfm').contains('PLAYLISTS').click()
    cy.wait(5000)
    cy.get('div.text-xfs').contains('Add New').click()
    cy.get('label.text-xfx').should('contain', 'Playlist name is required')
    cy.get('#playlistName')
      .type('Test-Playlist')
      .should('have.value', 'Test-Playlist')
    cy.get('span.text-xfs')
      .should('have.text', 'Choose assets to add to playlist')
      .click()
    cy.wait(5000)
    cy.get('div.overflow-scroll').should('be.visible')
    cy.log(this.value.assets)
    this.value.assets.forEach(function (element) {
      cy.selectAsset(element)
    })
  })
})
```